# Appending a DataFrame to a numpy array of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

How do I keep the 3d array structure and not have arr turn into a 1d array?

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6], [7,8,9], [120, 130, 140]])
data1 = pd.DataFrame([[3,3,3], [3,3,3], [3, 3, 3]])

arr = np.array([data])
print(arr)

arr = np.append(arr, data1)
print(arr)
```

output:

```
[[[  2   4   6]

  [  7   8   9]

  [120 130 140]]]

[  2   4   6   7   8   9 120 130 140   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3]
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use an **array** of dataframes? There are much better containers (a simple list for instance)

Comment: idk, im new to python. I was slicing a larger data frame up into seperate smaller dataframes and I wanted to store them as individual dataframes.

Comment: read the `np.append` docs - the whole thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to replace `np.append` with `np.vstack` with accepts 1 tuple and not many arguments

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6], [7,8,9], [120, 130, 140]])
data1 = pd.DataFrame([[3,3,3], [3,3,3], [3, 3, 3]])

arr = np.array([data])
arr1 = np.array([data1])

result = np.vstack( (arr,arr1))
print(result.shape)
print(result)
```

or just type

```
data.append(data1,ignore_index=True)
```